# How to get the contact first name?

Tags: apex

Below is my current query. I Program is a master to Application object. Application is also a details to the Contact object. How can I modify my query to get the first name of the contact?

```
[Select Name,Seminar1__r.Name,Seminar2__r.Name,Seminar3__r.Name,Seminar4__r.Name,Seminar5__r.Name,Seminar6__r.Name,Seminar7__r.Name,Seminar8__r.Name,Seminar9__r.Name,Seminar10__r.Name,Seminar11__r.Name
                                From Program__c
                                Where ID = :programID
                                ];
```

Comment: For clairty, using the following notation Parent => Child, your objects look like Program__c => Application__c and Contact => Application__c, correct?

Comment: The result of this query may have more contacts right? 
Program can have more than one applciations and each application aligned with its parent Contact?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question and database structure right, then you should be able to get all the "Application" children of the "Program" master using a subquery (child relationship):

```
Select Name, Seminar1__r.Name, (Select Contact__r.FirstName From Applications__r)
From Program__c
Where ID = :programID
```

Where "Applications" is a name of the child relationship to the "Application" from the "Program" master, and "Contact__r.FirstName" is a lookup to the Contact object from the "Application" object.

Comment: I added the (Select Contact__r.FirstName From Applications__r) but it didn't like it. Just to be clear, I need to go down a level and then up. Not a stand traversing scenario of just up a few levels or down. Is this clearer?

Comment: @ApexN-u-b I think you should read this article: [Understanding Relationship Names](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm)

Comment: I read it but it doesn't tell me how to go down and then up like (SELECT Onward_Israel_Program__r.Onward_Application__r.Contact__r.FirstName FROM Contact__r) which does not work but something like I need to do.